# Substract columns from each other based on a match in the column next to them?

Tags: mysql

just started my adventures in MYSQL and C# as a complete noob with just hobby experience in scripting languages and APIs, and while I manage to slowly find solutions for everything, this one I'm clueless and don't really know what to look for.

For now I would like to solve my issue during the MYSQL phase of my code.

My table looks something like this:

| Article1 | Amount1 | Article2 | Amount2 | Article3 | Amount3 | Article4 | Amount4 | Article5 | Amount5 | Article6 | Amount6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R | 4 | C | T0 | Z | 15 | Q | 4 | Y | 10 | X | 15 |
| C | 4 | T | 10 | R | 15 | Y | 4 | X | 10 | Z | 15 |
| C | 4 | R | 10 | T | 15 | X | 4 | Y | 10 | Z | 15 |
| Z | 4 | F | 10 | B | 15 | C | 4 | R | 10 | T | 15 |
| Q | 4 | X | 10 | Z | 15 | R | 4 | T | 10 | C | 15 |
| X | 4 | Z | 10 | Q | 15 | C | 4 | T | 10 | R | 15 |

I only want to look at entries where 'Z' and 'T' exist, I can do that easily with IN (,).
But then I want to substract the amount column next to 'Z' from the one next to 'T'.

'Z' aswell as 'T' have no fixed column, they can appear in every single one but are (at least) unique.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and bonus points for a solution I can understand so I can become better at this.

Thank you very much!

Edit:

My solution for now is to just create two new columns and run 6 update queries for each article+amount combination to look for the article I want and grab the corresponding amount value, like this:

| Article1 | Amount1 | Article2 | Amount2 | Article3 | Amount3 | Article4 | Amount4 | Article5 | Amount5 | Article6 | Amount6 | Amount_Article_Z | Amount_Article_T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R | 4 | C | 10 | Z | 15 | T | 4 | Y | 10 | X | 15 | 15 | 4 |
| C | 4 | T | 10 | R | 15 | Y | 4 | X | 10 | Z | 15 | 15 | 10 |
| C | 4 | R | 10 | T | 15 | X | 4 | Y | 10 | Z | 15 | 15 | 15 |
| Z | 4 | F | 10 | B | 15 | C | 4 | R | 10 | T | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| Q | 4 | X | 10 | Z | 15 | R | 4 | T | 10 | C | 15 | 15 | 10 |
| X | 4 | Z | 10 | Q | 15 | C | 4 | T | 10 | R | 15 | 10 | 10 |

The final step is to select the sum for each of the new column and substract it from the other.

Comment: This table desperately needs to be normalised.

Comment: There are inhouse tools using DBASE picking this up, there's probably no point in fixing this mess right now.

Comment: There is no "Next to" in a table. That you are relying on column position suggests that your table schema/design is bad. This table structure should be `article_number | article | amount`. Then this problem becomes much easier to solve.

Comment: I see a row `WHERE article3='T' AND article6='Z'`.  Is that what you are talking about?  Are you looking at a 'T' and a 'Z in the same column?  Show us the desired result.

Comment: I want to substract the corresponding amount column where an article='Z' from the corresponding amount column where an article='T'.

Comment: Updated the thread with how I managed to do it now, but it's really ugly.